# Rendering a table with dynamic headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to render a table with dynamic headers, I mean, I don't want to do something like this in the HTML

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            // THIS TABLE ROW IS WHAT I SAY
            <th>here info</th>
            <th>something here</th>
            <th>another header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="thing in things">
            <td>{{thing.asfs}}</td>
            <td>{{thing.asx}}</td>
            <td>{{person.dsf}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want something like this

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="head in heads">
        {{head}}
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="bar in bars">
        <td ng-repeat="foo in foos"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

that is only an example, I need to do it with this data:

```
{
   "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0":{
      "clicks":{
         "total":144,
         "real":1
      },
      "conversions":{
         "total":4,
         "amount":229
      },
      "cost":{
         "cpc":0.1999999999999995,
         "ecpc":1145.0000000000027,
         "total":28.79999999999993
      },
      "revenue":{
         "total":4,
         "epc":0.027777777777777776
      },
      "net":{
         "roi":-1.1612903225806457,
         "total":4
      },
     "name":"Traffic Source #2",
   },       
   "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4dbOTHER":{
      "clicks":{
         "total":144,
         "real":1
      },
      "conversions":{
         "total":4,
         "amount":229
      },
      "cost":{
         "cpc":0.1999999999999995,
         "ecpc":1145.0000000000027,
         "total":28.79999999999993
      },
      "revenue":{
         "total":4,
         "epc":0.027777777777777776
      },
      "net":{
         "roi":-1.1612903225806457,
         "total":4
      }
     "name":"Traffic Source #3"
   },

}
```

every key, like clicks, conversions, cost, etc, should be a `td`, it is just that I don't want static HTML.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

And also, sometimes that object will grow, could come up with some more keys like this one `55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0`

I did this fiddle with the exact same data I am receiving

http://jsfiddle.net/wLkz45qj/

Comment: Do `$scope.peopleKeys = Object.keys(people);`, then `<th ng-repeat="personKey in peopleKeys">{{personKey}}</th>`.

Comment: @jperezov but how do I adapt it to the data I am receiving ? because actually you should see that I am receiving an object, not an array

Comment: So you have differnt objects with different dimensions, how you imaging them to fit in one table ?

Comment: @vittore yes, all of of that should fit in one table, look at my edit.

Comment: @TheUnnamed so basically you need all keys from two levels?

Comment: @vittore with that info I need a regular table like this http://postimg.org/image/k2o7myc05/

Comment: @vittore actually that table I paste above, is the one I need, I get it from the docs off my app.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: 
 What you need to do is first convert you inconvenient object to array of objects with simple structure, and then use my code , i.e.

```
{
 a: {
   b:{ 
     c: 'x'
   }
 }
}
```

will turn into

```
[[ a, {  'b.c' : 'x' }], ...]
```

or just

```
[{ _id : a , 'b.c' :'x'}, ...]
```

easiest way to do that is to use lodash or underscore ( check map, flatMap, pairs etc)

@jperezov showed you core idea, little bit detailed example:

```
 $scope.peopleKeys = Object.keys(people[0])
```

and

```
 <table>
   <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th ng-repeat="personKey in peopleKeys">
       {{ personKey }}
    </th>
   </tr>

   <tr ng-repeat='p in people'>
      <th>{{ $index }}</th>
      <td ng-repeat="personKey in peopleKeys">
       {{ p[personKey] }}
      </td>
   </tr>

 </table>
```

You may also have some dictionary with display names:

```
$scope.displayNames = {
  id: 'ID',
  firstName: 'First Name'
```

...

```
}
```

and then your header going to be:

```
   <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th ng-repeat="personKey in peopleKeys">
       {{ displayNames[personKey] }}
    </th>
   </tr>
```

PS: OR you can just use [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info)

Comment: I get this, but in the person in the example the data comes from an array, in this case I am receiving an object, I should take that into account.

Comment: @TheUnnamed can you show detailed example of data you are receiving in the question?

Comment: the data I paste above is the full data. That is all I am receiving

Comment: @TheUnnamed see my comment for question

Comment: see that fiddle and the edit I did, please. Also you can see the json object, I just change it.

Comment: awesome but I don't see how I can adapt that to my code. Thank you anyways.

Comment: I will be deleting this question and doing a new one with some more specifics. This is verbose, sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function PeopleCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $scope.headers=[];
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.LoadMyJson = function() {
          for (var s in myJson){
            $scope.data.push(s);
            if ($scope.headers.length < 1) 
                for (var prop in myJson[s]){
                prop.data = [];
                $scope.headers.push({th:prop, td: []});
              }
          }
          for (var s in $scope.data){
            for (var prop in $scope.headers){
                var header = $scope.headers[prop].th;
                  var data = myJson[$scope.data[s]][header];
                     $scope.headers[prop].td.push(data);
            }
          }
    };

}
```

What you're looking for is something like this, I think: 
http://jsfiddle.net/wLkz45qj/8/

Maybe iterate another time over "inner" for formatting.

Comment: and how do I render it in the html?     `<tr>
        <td ng-repeat='data in headers'>
        <div ng-repeat='inner in data.td'>
        {{inner}}
        </div></td>`, what should I use instead of {{inner?}}
    </tr>

Comment: use `<span ng-repeat='(prop, val) in inner'>{{prop}}:{{val}}</span>`: see http://jsfiddle.net/mgayxjtp/